# PHP XMLReader parent and child with the same name

Tags: php, xmlreader

I'm having lots of trouble trying to read the following XML file:

```
<Results>
  <Art>
    <Art>
      <Code>100</Code>
    </Art>
    <Art>
      <Code>200</Code>
    </Art>
    <Art>
      <Code>300</Code>
    </Art>
  <Art>
</Results>
```

The problem I'm facing is that both the parent and it's childs are named "Art".

The following code works fine only if the parent is named for example "Arts" and it's children are named "Art":

```
$xml_path = '/path_to_file/file.xml';
$reader = new XMLReader();
if ($reader->open($xml_path)) {
  while ($reader->read() && $reader->name !== 'Art');
  while ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name === 'Art') {
    $node = simplexml_load_string($reader->readOuterXML());

    // Get the "Code" in the current "Art".
    $current_code = (string)$node->Code;
    // Do something with $current_code...

    $reader->next('Art');
  }
  $reader->close();
}
```

But as both the parent and it's childs are named "Art" I can't seem to figure how to get only the childs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with the following code:

```
$xml_path = '/path_to_file/file.xml';
$reader = new XMLReader();
if ($reader->open($xml_path)) {
  while ($reader->read() && $reader->name !== 'Art');
  while ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name === 'Art') {
    $node = simplexml_load_string($reader->readOuterXML());

    // NEW CODE!
    if (isset($node->Art)) {
      $reader->read();
    }

    // Get the "Code" in the current "Art".
    $current_code = (string)$node->Code;
    // Do something with $current_code...

    $reader->next('Art');
  }
  $reader->close();
}
```

Was driving me mad XD